# how to open a file regardless of it's extension using java code?

Tags: java

i usually use this code to open files in java :

```
try {

            File file = new File("C:\\justifadhesion\\justif.jpg");
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            desktop.open(file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(G.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

and it works, but there are cases where i can be sure if the file is a jpg or a png. is there a way i can modify my code so that it can open the file without having me precise it's extension in the path?

Comment: use a regular expression maybe?

Comment: Are the possible formats jpg and png only?

Comment: Regex shouldn't work in this context.

Comment: yes jpg and png are the only possible format in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage it as follows:

```
File file = new File("C:\\justifadhesion\\justif.jpg");
if (!file.exists()) {
    file = new File("C:\\justifadhesion\\justif.png");
    if (file.exists()) {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        try {
            desktop.open(file);
            //...other business logic
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(G.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
        Logger.getLogger(G.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, "The file does not exist");
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** First check the file with one extension e.g. `.jpg` and if doesn't exist, check the file with the other extension (which will be `.png` in this case). If it exists, try to open it (i.e. open it inside `try...catch` block) otherwise log the error that the file is does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    File file = new File("C:\\justifadhesion\\justif.jpg");
    if (!file.exists()) {
         file = new File("C:\\justifadhesion\\justif.png");
    }
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    desktop.open(file);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(G.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Use a nested `try-catch` block. Try to fetch `jpg` initially, if it doesn't work, then fetch `png`.

No need to list all the files because you have just 2 options.

If you were to have more than two extensions, then listing the directory and finding the file would be a better option.

Comment: This would not work as new File("path_that_does_not_exist.jpg") does not throw FileNotFoundException

Comment: The new File(xxx) does not throw any exception - or you wouldn't be able to create a file. You don't need the inner try block if use "if (!file.exists()) file =" to set second value

Comment: @DuncG how about now

Comment: That should work though strangely Desktop.open will throw IllegalArgumentException if the second file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use File.list() to enumerate all files in a folder, and then see if there is a JPG or PNG in there. See https://stackabuse.com/java-list-files-in-a-directory/ for some examples.

The extension is part of the file name, so you need to include it (with some exceptions, like .exe, .bat or .com).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: "You could use File.list() to enumerate all files in a folder, and then see if there is a JPG or PNG in there." - Which part of that did you not understand?

Comment: The part you wrote in quotes does not qualify as an answer (imo). Most of your answer is dependent on the link and if the link failed in the future, then your answer will be useless. A quality answer will have some piece of code to achieve what is asked in the question.

Comment: I expect any StackOverflow user to be able to find the Javadoc for a certain class and function, given the class and function name. I cannot provide code for a problem that is as vaguely defined as OP's.

Comment: If you think the question is vaguely defined, then leave a comment (and/or downvote the question), or vote to close the question.